# how to select an item in a treeview using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ui-automation, win32gui

I wanted to select an item in a tree view? I'm able to get the control of the window Tree view as **SysTreeView32** using **win32gui.EnumChildWindow** function, but not able to get the details of the items inside the tree.

Can you suggest any method to automate tree view? i found things like pywinauto, PyCTreeCntrl or win32apis, but i don't know how to use any of these thing for TreeView

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of tree view automation with pywinauto

```
import pywinauto

pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'PuTTY Configuration', class_name='PuTTYConfigBox')[0]
window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
ctrl = window['TreeView']  #SysTreeView32
ctrl.GetItem([u'Connection']).Click()  #Click on a top level element
ctrl.GetItem([u'Connection', u'Data']).Click()  #Click on a sub element
```

Comment: Thank you :) Its working for me, I'm able to click on the elements. But the end sub elements are check boxes. so even if im clicking on it, the  check boxes are not getting selected. 
In my case the sub element `u'Data'` is a check box, even if im clicking on `u'Data'`, the check box remain unchecked.

Comment: Try Check() instead of Click()

Comment: Let me try.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did to solve my problem. For me, Check() would not work. However, double-clicking on the item on the item box or its parent rectangle would.

So, here's what I did:
1. Retrieved the rectangle co-ordinates using

ctrl_rect = TreeView.GetItem(Path).Rectangle()

1. Double - Click on the element using

Window['TreeView'].DoubleClickInput(coords=(ctrl_rect.left, ctrl_rect.top))

I used the hints provided at http://sourceforge.net/p/pywinauto/discussion/529287/thread/120750c6/

I hope this helps